# ReactiveUI WPF - Getting the last word of a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I know this is a trivial program but I am Learning ReactiveUI and am new to the whole MVVN in the first place. I am trying to get the first and last name from a full name entered in a text box and show them in separate text blocks.

I got this working but my question is, is there a way to do the last name with just the LINQ style extensions or do I have to call another function using `select(GetLast)` as shown below? And, If there is a way to do it with LINQ style extensions, is it better to do it that way or with the `select(GetLast)`?

And if there's any other input you want to give, it would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance for any help given.

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```cs
private string _fullName;
public string FullName
{
    get => _fullName;
    set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _fullName, value);
}

private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> _firstName;
public string FirstName => _firstName.Value;

private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> _lastName;
public string LastName => _lastName.Value;

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    _lastName = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.FullName)
        .Select(full => full?.Trim())
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .Where(full => full != null)
        .Select(GetLast)                                   //<-- Point of question
        .ToProperty(this, x => x.LastName, out _lastName);

    _firstName = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.FullName)
        .Select(full => full?.Trim())
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .Where(full => full != null)
        .Select(full => full.Split(' ')[0])
        .ToProperty(this, nameof(FirstName), out _firstName);
}

private string GetLast(string name)
{
    string[] splitName = name.Split(' ');
    if (splitName.Length > 2)
        return splitName[splitName.Length - 1];
    if (splitName.Length == 2)
        return splitName[1];                
    return string.Empty;
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Label Content="_Full Name:"
    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
    FontWeight="SemiBold"
    Target="{Binding ElementName=fullNameTextBox}"/>
<TextBlock Text="First Name:"
    Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"
    FontWeight="SemiBold"
    Padding="5,5,0,5"/>
<TextBlock Text="Last Name:"
    Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2"
    FontWeight="SemiBold"
    Padding="5,5,0,5"/>

<TextBox x:Name="fullNameTextBox"
    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"
    MinWidth="150"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="firstNameTextBlock"
    Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"
    MinWidth="75"
    Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="lastNameTextBlock"
    Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3"
    MinWidth="75"
    Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
this.WhenActivated(disposableRegistration =>
{
    this.OneWayBind(ViewModel,
            vm => vm.FirstName,
            v => v.firstNameTextBlock.Text)
        .DisposeWith(disposableRegistration);

    this.OneWayBind(ViewModel,
            vm => vm.LastName,
            v => v.lastNameTextBlock.Text)
        .DisposeWith(disposableRegistration);

    this.Bind(ViewModel,
            vm => vm.FullName,
            v => v.fullNameTextBox.Text)
        .DisposeWith(disposableRegistration);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATED**

how about

```
_lastName = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.FullName)
.Select(full => full?.Trim())
.DistinctUntilChanged()
.Where(full => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(full))
.Select(x => x.Split(' ').Last())
.ToProperty(this, x => x.LastName, out _lastName);
```

As for "is this better", honestly, that's your call.  I think this is pretty straightforward - it's just linq - but it might be that your co-workers don't speak linq well and would prefer a a seperate method they can unit test and easily grasp.

Comment: this should also work with `First()` for _firstName if you want to make that a little neater, by the way.

Comment: When I add ```.Last()``` I get a warning: ```Observable.Last<TSource>(IObservable<TSource>) is obsolete: The blocking operation is no longer supported. Instead, use the async version in combination with C# and Visual Basic async/await. In case you need a blocking operation, use Wait to convert the resulting observable sequence to a Task object and block.```

Comment: @Rick Bryant When I use ```LastAsync().ToProperty(this, x=> x.LastName, out _lastName);``` I get an error: ```The type arguments for method 'OAPHCreationHelperMixin.ToProperty<TObj, TRet>(Iobservable<TRet>, tObj, Expression<Func<Tobj,Tret>>, Tret, bool, IScheduler)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly```

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a poke through that.  Thanks for the information.

Comment: Oh, of course, it's trying to do `Last` on the Observable, not the array.

Let me edit.

Comment: Thank you. I'm at a point that I can read Linq statements pretty well but still have trouble composing them. I had to add ```Select(x => x.Split(' ').Last()).Select(x => x == FirstName ? "" : x)``` because, when there was only one word in the ```FullName``` textbox,  just having the first ```.Select(...)``` was assigning that one word to both first and last name. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: you can probably avoid that with your `Where` clause.  .`Where(full => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(full) && full.Contains(" "))` for example.